# How to query with lead() values not in current range

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I´m having problems querying when lead() values are not within the range of current row, rows on the range's edge return null lead() values.

Let’s say  I have a simple table to keep track of continuous counters

```
create table anytable
( wseller integer  NOT NULL,
  wday    date     NOT NULL,
  wshift  smallint NOT NULL,
  wconter numeric(9,1) )
```

with the following values

```
wseller      wday wshift wcounter
      1 2016-11-30     1    100.5
      1 2017-01-03     1    102.5
      1 2017-01-25     2    103.2
      1 2017-02-05     2    106.1
      2 2015-05-05     2    81.1
      2 2017-01-01     1    92.1
      2 2017-01-01     2    93.1
      3 2016-12-01     1    45.2
      3 2017-01-05     1    50.1
```

and want net units for current year

```
wseller       wday wshift units
      1 2017-01-03      1     2
      1 2017-01-25      2   0.7
      1 2017-02-05      2   2.9
      2 2017-01-01      1    11
      2 2017-01-01      2     1
      3 2017-01-05      1   4.9
```

If I use

```
seletc wseller, wday, wshift, wcounter-lead(wcounter) over (partition by wseller order by  wseller, wday desc, wshift desc) 
from anytable
where wday>='2017-01-01'
```

gives me nulls on the first wseller by partition. I´m using this query within a large CTE.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The scope of a window function takes into account conditions in the WHERE clause. Move the condition to the outer query:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        wseller, wday, wshift, 
        wcounter- lead(wcounter) over (partition by wseller order by wday desc, wshift desc)
    from anytable
    ) s
where wday >= '2017-01-01'
order by wseller, wday, wshift

 wseller |    wday    | wshift | ?column? 
---------+------------+--------+----------
       1 | 2017-01-03 |      1 |      2.0
       1 | 2017-01-25 |      2 |      0.7
       1 | 2017-02-05 |      2 |      2.9
       2 | 2017-01-01 |      1 |     11.0
       2 | 2017-01-01 |      2 |      1.0
       3 | 2017-01-05 |      1 |      4.9
(6 rows)
```

Comment: i beg your pardon, my original sqlfiddle was wrong or incomplete, it should say **where h.product=d.product and h.start_day<=d.del_date** in order to find the right price for each date range, please check it again [sorry about it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3090a/7/0)